# Understanding method / class calls in Java

Tags: java, string, arraylist, blackjack

I am attempting to make a very basic Black Jack game I have it broke into three simple classes, but I am extremely new to Java and I am a terrible coder but I need to learn this for work. I am having some major difficulty understanding how I am suppose to call methods and classes. I figured out the basic structure of the game like how to create the cards and how to enter the game and exit the game. I just can't figure out the game play itself. This is what I have created so far. Please any advice and direction so I can understand this would be great I am desperate.

BlackJack.java

```java
import java.util.*;

public class BlackJack4 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    // write your code here

        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        String playGame = "";

        System.out.print("Wanna play some BlackJack? \n");
        System.out.print("Type yes or no \n");

        playGame = keyboard.nextLine();

        if (playGame.equals ("yes"))
        {
            /*
            This is the area I need help in figuring out. 
             */
        }
        else if (playGame.equals("no")) //Player decided to no play the game
        {
            System.out.print("Thank you for playing with us today.\n");
            System.out.print("To exit the game please press enter.");
            scan.nextLine();
            System.exit(0);
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.print("Sorry you did something wrong. Please try again.\n");
            System.out.print("To exit the game please press enter.");
            scan.nextLine();
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }
}
```

Deck.java

```java
import java.util.*;

public class Deck {
    ArrayList<Cards> cards = new ArrayList<Cards>();

    String[] Suits = { "Clubs", "Diamonds", "Hearts", "Spades"};
    String[] Ranks = {null, "A", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "J", "Q", "K"};

    public Deck() {
        int d = Suits.length * Ranks.length;

        String[] deck = new String[d];
        for (int i = 0; i < Ranks.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < Suits.length; j++) {
                deck[Suits.length * i + j] = Ranks[i] + " of " + Suits[j];
            }
        }
    }

    public void shuffle(){//shuffle the deck when its created
        Collections.shuffle(this.cards);
    }
}
```

Cards.java

```
public class Cards {
    private String suit;
    private String rank;

    public Cards(){}

    public Cards(String suit, String rank){
        this.suit = suit;
        this.rank = rank;
    }

    public  String getSuit(){
        return suit;
    }
    /* public void setSuit(String suit){
        this.suit = suit;
    }*/
    public String getRank(){
        return rank;
    }
    /*
    public void setRank(String value){
        this.rank = rank;
    }*/
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.format("%s of %s", rank, suit);
    }
}
```

Comment: Usually such games have a `while` loop with a condition indicating the game is still in progress. Loosen the logic and figure out a simple while loop that will go on.. For starters it might be `while user does not hit q, get input..` 

Sidenote, you do not need multiple scanners, and never forget to `scanner.close`

Comment: You can use `System.out.println` method instead of `System.out.print`, it will allow you not to add `\n` after each line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This kind of task is not very easy level, there is a lot of things to do here, perhaps you have to start from some more basic stuff. But if you sure you want to get through, here some advice and code:
You have to add `score` field to the Card class(single name is better than plural for class, as well as lower case first letter for variables, it's some code conventions). Not easy because Ace can have multivalue.
Use LinkedList instead of ArrayList as Deck.cards. It's more similar with real game when dealer polls a card each time.

put `this.cards.add(cards);` intead of 'deck[Suits.length * i + j] = Ranks[i] + " of " + Suits[j];' you dont need this String array at all. And the most important part is the sceleton you can put to the place you pointed, where help is most expected:

```
    private static void playGame(Scanner scan) {
        Deck deck = new Deck();
        String playGame;
        Integer yourScore = 0;
        Random random = new Random();
        Boolean playerEnough = false;
        Boolean dealerEnough = false;
        Integer dealerScore = 0;
        deck.shuffle();
        while ((yourScore <= 21 && dealerScore <= 21) && (!dealerEnough || !playerEnough)) {
            if (yourScore == 0) {
                yourScore += getCardScore(deck, "Player");
                yourScore += getCardScore(deck, "Player");
            }
            if (dealerScore == 0) {
                dealerScore += getCardScore(deck, "Dealer");
                dealerScore += getCardScore(deck, "Dealer");
            }
            if (!playerEnough) {
                System.out.println("Want a card?");
                playGame = scan.nextLine();
                if (playGame.equals("yes")) {
                    yourScore += getCardScore(deck, "Player");
                } else {
                    System.out.println("PlayerDone");
                    playerEnough = true;
                }
            }
            if (!dealerEnough) {
                if (random.nextBoolean()) {
                    dealerScore += getCardScore(deck, "Dealer");
                } else {
                    System.out.println("DealerDone");
                    dealerEnough = true;
                }
            }
            System.out.println(yourScore + " [p] : [d] " + dealerScore);    
        }
        // decide who is a winner
    }


    private static Integer getCardScore(Deck deck, String who) {
        System.out.print(who + " given: ");
        Cards cards = deck.cards.pollFirst();
        System.out.println(cards);
        return cards.getScore();
    }
```

this can help you to make a step further, or not, then I suggest you to solve some smaller exercises.

Answer (score 0):

Now I am relatively new to Java so I assume somebody with more knowledge will come along and be able to help you more but this is what I have for now:

1) I recommend you remove the `public Cards() {} constructor` as you might by accident create an invalid card (having set no attributes).

2) As stated by the comment I would do a while loop that checks for a press of a key and then does a correlating action.

```
while (gameIsRunning) {
   if (key1 is pressed) {
   ...
   }

   ...

   if (key10 is pressed) {
   ...
   System.out.println("You won! Game over.");
   gameIsRunning = false;
   }
}
```

I would define somewhere in a class or method the procedure of one round of the game or write all the helper methods for it and then throw them in this loop structure. 
Alternatively you can prompt the user with text and await text input for the next action.

Hope I could help!

Answer (score 0):

A somewhat out-of-fashion, but still very effective, method of software design is called the *waterfall* process: Start at the very top level and work your way down to the details rather than the other way around.  For example, start with the overall flow of the game:

```
public static class Game {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        while (/* player wishes to continue */) {
            /* play a hand */
        }
        System.out.println('Thank you for playing.');
    }
}
```

Now, consider what needs to be done for the things that are comments above. How do you wish to communicate with the player to get his intentions? Keyboard? GUI? That will determine how you flesh out that part. Then decide the overall strategy of the "play a hand" part, and you'll get the next level:

```
public class Game {
    . . .
     public void playOneHand(Player p) {
         /* create new shuffled deck */
         /* deal initial cards */
         while (/* player has choices */) {
             /* get player choices */
         }
         /* play dealer hand */
         /* display result */
     }
}
public class Player {
    /* Maybe actions should be numbers from a menu? An enum class? */
    public String getPlayerAction(String prompt) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println(prompt);
        return sc.nextLine();
    }
}
```

That's level 2. Now start to fill in each of those comments, which will take you to level 3, and so on. Eventually you'll get down to the details of cards and numbers, but not until you're ready to put them somewhere.